# How do I calculate something inside a 'for' loop?

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment in which I have to move a simulated robot across the screen in a loop - I've got that part down, however, between loops, I also have to print the percentage of area covered with each movement - that's my issue.

I googled a bit and even found someone with the same problem, however, I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly.

This code was offered:

```
percent_complete = 0

for i in range(5):
    percent_complete += 20
    print('{}% complete'.format(percent_complete))
```

However, after an error, further googling revealed that only worked with certain versions

so I used this code:

```
percent_complete = 0

for i in range(5):
        percent_complete += 20
        print '% complete' % (percent_complete)
```

And, at the very least, it now executes the code, however, the output when printing is the following:

```
Here we go!
hello
omplete
hello
(omplete
hello
<omplete
hello
Pomplete
hello
domplete
```

What is the cause of this? I assume because one of the codes had to be edited, the other parts do as well, but I'm not sure what needs to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in range(5):
    percent_complete += 20
    print '%d complete' % (percent_complete)
```

You were missing the `d` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

The first version only works in Python 3 because it uses `print` as a function. You're probably looking for the following:

```
percent_complete = 0
for i in xrange(5):
    percent_complete += 20
    print '{0} complete'.format(percent_complete)
```

Your other code doesn't do what you intend to do because it now display the number as a string. What you want is that the number is properly converted to a string first and then displayed in the string. The function `format` does that for you.

You can also use Ansari's approach which explicitly specifies that `percent_complete` is a number (with the `d` specifier).

Answer (score 1):

To add to/correct above answers:

The reason your first example didn't work isn't because print isn't a function, but because you left out the argument specifier.  Try `print('{0}% complete'.format(percent_complete))`.  The 0 inside the brackets is the crucial factor there.

Comment: Yes, but the OP mentioned that the plain {} version only worked "in certain versions", so presumably it didn't work in the version the OP tried (or else it would have, well, worked).